# Excel after saving 10 files give me error

Tags: vba, excel, csv, excel-2007

I have created one script which is launched on click button, so it loads CSV file from path and format and than save it. As I have files from 1...10000 so I made file like 1.txt and so on.
I am getting problem is when it start process everything goes fine but after 10-13 files it give error and excel closes. Following are codes I am using. Please assist me where I am doing mistake. I think I am doing mistake in array I tried redim but but that one gives me same error. This is sub which I placed on my button to start process. As I have more than thousands files so please suggest me solution.

```
Sub WorkbooksLoop()
' get the list of filenames
Dim pageStart As Integer
Dim pageEnd As Integer
pageStart = CInt(Cells(3, "C").Value) ' getting from cell of excel sheet
pageEnd = CInt(Cells(4, "C").Value) ' getting from cell of excel sheet
Dim Filenames(44) As String ' variable I know there are 44 files


For j = pageStart To pageEnd
        Filenames(j) = CStr(j) + ".txt"
Next j


On Error GoTo NoFilenames

Dim controllerwb As Workbook
Set controllerwb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim fname As Variant

Dim rootPath As String
rootPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
rootPath = rootPath & "\"

For Each fname In Filenames
    ' Make the controller active
    controllerwb.Activate

    On Error Resume Next
    ' If activate fails, then the workbook isn't open
    Workbooks(fname).Activate
    ' If activate fails, then the workbook isn't open
    If Err <> 0 Then
        OpenFile (rootPath & fname)
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        wb.Activate
    ' Otherwise, workbook is already open, refer to it by name
    Else
        OpenFile (rootPath & fname)
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    End If

    ' do something to the open workbook my process to format sheet
        deletingRowsColumns
        ledgerSetup
        resizeColumns
        columnLines
        columnAlignments
        mergeTitles
        settingNames
    wb.Close
Next fname
NoFilenames:
End Sub
```

Comment: Your inappropriate use of `On Error Resume Next` is potentially hiding error(s) which are occurring in the called procedures like `deletingRowsColumns`, `ledgerSetup`, etc.

Comment: I would suggest adding `On Error GoTo 0` immediately *after* the `End If` statement. This will resume normal error handling, and help identify errors in any of the other called procedures.

Comment: Also consider describing at which line the error raises, and what specific error message you are receiving.

Comment: Also when the Debugger kicks in, see if it's the same workbook, that is causing the errors.Is the error in the folder loop or the other codes that are being called? Here's another example of looping through a folder.[Loop through folder](http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Loop%20Through%20Folder)

Comment: Additionally: (1) Don't rely on `ActiveWorkbook`. Always grab the workbook object you get when you open or create a workbook. (2) Both the `(Err <> 0)` and `(Err = 0)` parts of IF statement are doing the same thing (Workbook shouldn't need to be active) (3) I don't see a Save anywhere. (4) Put a `Debug.Print pageStart & " - " & pageEnd` before the FOR loop (5) Put a `Debug.Print wb.name` before `deletingRowsColumns` (6) Write down the error reported by Excel before dying

Answer (score 0):

I have done everything and recode it in different way. But still after 10-20 files it through an error. As I was using windows machine on my mac as virtual machine, so I just thought why not i try it on mac with microsoft office. And have to change just forward slashes of directory to colon(interesting I thought it should be back slash but that is how vba was doing) and it worked I get alert of some file not saving, but it is ok at least I could do 1000 files easily rest I can save manually. But it realy work although vba engine is little bit slower in mac but who cares I just leave it for few hours to do all files for me. 
Thanks for all your help. Mike yes I need to learn more about ActiveWorkbook and scripting. I will try to do as you told me but my work done. Thanks